# Android MediaRecorder start failed -19

Tags: android, runtimeexception, mediarecorder

I am developing an Android Streaming Application using Live555. Therefore, I decided to record audio und video separatly to handle the streams. But unfortunatly, I got an RuntimeException when I try to start the recording.

```
private void startRecording() throws IOException {
    if (videoRecorder == null) {
        videoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        videoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(preview.getHolder().getSurface());
        videoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        videoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        videoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        videoRecorder.setVideoSize(320,24);
        videoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(25);
        videoRecorder.setOutputFile(video.getFD());
    }

    if (audioRecorder == null) {
        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFile(audio.getFD());
    }

    if (!isStreaming) {
        videoRecorder.prepare();
        videoRecorder.start(); // RuntimeException
        audioRecorder.prepare();
        audioRecorder.start();
        isStreaming = true;

    } else {
        stopRecording();
        isStreaming = false;
    }

    Thread t = new Thread(new LiveStreamer(this, video, audio));
    t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    t.start();
}
```

I searched on the Internet for a while, but none of the successed solutions worked for me. Here's the logcat:

```
    01-02 16:17:09.355: E/MediaRecorder(11256): start failed: -19
01-02 16:17:09.355: D/AndroidRuntime(11256): Shutting down VM
01-02 16:17:09.355: W/dalvikvm(11256): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41884da0)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256): Process: de.douglasmedia.LiveCam, PID: 11256
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at de.douglasmedia.LiveCam.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:139)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at de.douglasmedia.LiveCam.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:116)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at de.douglasmedia.LiveCam.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:66)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
01-02 16:17:09.355: E/AndroidRuntime(11256):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the permission section of my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camra" />
```

Somewhere, I have read that the problem is the video size. So, I tried it with the allowed video sizes, but got the same error. Does someone have a idea how to fix this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You made mistake in manifest (camra): <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camra" />

Answer (score 1):

1. Your video size is not correct, it should be 320x240 rather than 320x24. typo?
2. Audio Encoder not set, you need to add below line.

   audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
   audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
3. What's the purpose to use two MediaRecorder? Maybe it's better to use one MediaRecorder for both audio and video.

Below code section works fine for me on MotoG device:

```
private void startRecording() throws IOException {
    String storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if (mVideoRecorder == null) {
        mVideoRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mVideoRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mVideoRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoSize(320,240);
        mVideoRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                storage + "/video.mp4"));
        FileDescriptor fd = fileOutputStream.getFD();

        mVideoRecorder.setOutputFile(fd);
    }

    if (mAudioRecorder == null) {
        mAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                storage + "/audio.mp4"));
        FileDescriptor fd = fileOutputStream.getFD();
        mAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(fd);
    }

    mVideoRecorder.prepare();
    mVideoRecorder.start(); // RuntimeException
    mAudioRecorder.prepare();
    mAudioRecorder.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've removed the audio part to record only the pictures from camera into a file (its enough for testing purposes). But unfortunatly, I got the same error ;-(

Comment: Just try code section pasted above, it works fine for me on MotoG device.

Comment: I tried this, but still got the same error ;-( I've tested it on my Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 4.4.2)